# PHP check if string contains url without http://

Tags: php, string, url, preg-match, contains

What is the best way to find if a string contains a url?

I'm writing a chatbox and need to deny the posting of urls in it...

```
if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z;.\/?:@=_#&%~,+$]+/', $clean_message, $matches))
{
die('INVALID!');
}
```

seems to do the trick for urls that contain http:// but i need to also be able to deny urls such as youtube.com and if an ipaddress is posted etc..

I need to keep the chatbox clean from users spamming urls!

Comment: Why bother?  You'll never stop stuff like www [dot] youtube [dot] com.  Filter for automated spam postings, and let it go?

Comment: I can spam a URL like this: s t a c k o v e r f l o w . c o m

Comment: You can do like Office Communicator and just add `_` to known web protocols. Like: `_http://www.example.com`. Then it's up to the person on the other end to follow through.

Comment: @Brad, str_replace("[dot]", ".", $url);

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, str_replace(" ", "", $url);

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Links are not put in href tags automatically so no need to make links invalid.

Comment: @E3pO: Whatever rule you come up with, I can come up with a way to circumvent it.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best you can do is something like:

```
/[\w\d\.]+\.(com|org|ca|net|uk)/
```

and add in all other common suffixes. Doing something like:

```
/[\w\d\.]+\.[\w\d]{1,3}/
```

might be too generic but would catch pretty much anything that looked like a URL.

Comment: That works great now but we run into the issue of people saying things such as "wow.that.is.cool!"

Comment: wow.that.is.cool could be a url, I don't think there's any way to know that it's not.

Comment: You're going to have to decide where to draw the line between letting some urls through, and not letting users enter something they want that isn't a url. You're going to end up with a bit in each anyway you do it.

Comment: Actually I just realized there's another issue, this would block "100.00". You should probably replace the [\w\d\.] with something like [\w\d\.]*\w[\w\d\.]*